# Python itertools.combinations_with_replacement not returning all combinations

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-itertools

I have written a simple python program:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.5
import sys, itertools

sCharacters = '123'
for iCombinationLength in range(0, len(sCharacters)+1):
  for aCombination in itertools.combinations_with_replacement(sCharacters, iCombinationLength):
    print(''.join(aCombination))
```

This outputs the following:

```
1
2
3
11
12
13
22
23
33
111
112
113
122
123
133
222
223
233
333
```

However for it to be all combinations of the numbers 1 2 and 3, it would need to include:

```
311
312
313
321
322
323
331
332
333
```

And as you can see above, it does not.  I have seen other posts giving the  combinations_with_replacement function given as the solution to get all possible combinations of the characters passed in.  Yet this does not seem to be happening.  What am I doing wrong here, and how can I get all possible combinations of the characters in the characters variable?

Thanks for your time ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"combinations" is an order-insensitive term; if you have `113`, then you don't need `131` or `311`, because all of them are the same "combination" (if the input sequence to `combinations_with_replacement` is unique, you could view the outputs as being all unique values after converting to `collections.Counter`; regardless of order, two `1`s and a `3` is just `collections.Counter({1: 2, 3:1})`).

If you want an order sensitive version of `combinations_with_replacement` (so `113`, `131` and `311` are all separate outputs), use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) with the `repeat` argument (`repeat` must be passed by keyword due to design of `product`, where it takes variable length positional arguments):

```
sCharacters = '123'
for iCombinationLength in range(0, len(sCharacters)+1):
  for aCombination in itertools.product(sCharacters, repeat=iCombinationLength):
    print(''.join(aCombination))
```

Comment: Perfect!! thanks for the solution, much appreciated.

Comment: If you want to know more about what `itertools.product` is actually doing, read about [Cartesian products](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product).